# Getting ERROR 000622 when checking for arcpy.DefineProjection_management?

Tags: arcpy, coordinate-system, arcgis-10.2, error-000628, error-000622

The purpose of my code is to create a loop that copies shapefiles from a folder to my folder and change its projection 'GCS_WGS_1984'. Each shapefile starts with the year follow by the month and '_rfe.shp' (ex. 200701_rfe.2007) which is why I made the loop the way it is. When the first stage of the loop starts I get a error saying that in my arcpy.DefineProjection_management function, my projection is not valid.

How can I get my projection to be 'GCS_WGS_1984'?

```
        Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Elvis\Desktop\Spring\Geog376\lab05\lab05.py", line 32, in <module>
    arcpy.DefineProjection_management(shp, projection)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 8184, in DefineProjection
    raise e
ExecuteError: ERROR 000622: Failed to execute (Define Projection). Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000628: Cannot set input into parameter coor_system.
```

---

```
    #import modules
    import arcpy
    import os


     # set workspace(This is where all your processing will be done)
     #arcpy.env.workspace = 'S://376/spring14/eherrer2/'
```

arcpy.env.workspace = 'C://workspace/'

```
     workspace = 'C://workspace/'
     otherFolder = 'C://folder/'

    backup = []    
    for shapefiles in range(1,13):
        arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(outPut+'2007'+str(shapefiles).zfill(2)+'_rfe.shp',inPut+'2007'+str(shapefiles).zfill(2)+'_rfe.shp')
        shp = '2007'+str(shapefiles).zfill(2)+'_rfe.shp'
        describeShp = arcpy.Describe(shp)
        shpSR = describeShp.SpatialReference

        projection = 'GCS_WGS_1984'
        arcpy.DefineProjection_management(shp, projection)
        print 'GCS {0}'.format (shpSR.GCSname)
```

Answer (score 4):

Try replacing `'GCS_WGS_1984'` with the [factory code](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/002z/pdf/geographic_coordinate_systems.pdf), which is a bombproof method of assigning a spatial reference.  This is how you would put it together:

```
    ...
    for shapefiles in range(1,13):
        arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(outPut+'2007'+str(shapefiles).zfill(2)+'_rfe.shp',inPut+'2007'+str(shapefiles).zfill(2)+'_rfe.shp')
        shp = '2007'+str(shapefiles).zfill(2)+'_rfe.shp'
        describeShp = arcpy.Describe(shp)
        shpSR = describeShp.SpatialReference

        projection = arcpy.SpatialReference(4326)
        arcpy.DefineProjection_management(shp, projection)
        print 'GCS {0}'.format (shpSR.GCSname)
```

Also, you should properly format your workspace:

```
arcpy.env.workspace = 'C:/path/to/your/ws'
```

Comment: Thank you Aaron. I messed around with your code and found out that you can just put the factory code in the Define Projection function.   arcpy.DefineProjection_management(shp, 4326)

Comment: how did you find out 'GCS_WGS_1984' has the SpatialRefernce code of 4326? I tried using the describe and spatial reference objects on a feature but it keeps giving me back just the objects name...

Answer (score 3):

You haven't defined a workspace. So your script doesn't know where to find the shp variable. Add a workspace or set the full path to your shp variable.